# Error 405 Method not allowed

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

I am desgining a web app using google app engine and python and 
While extracting the form data ie. parameter values  using the get request the following error occurs during the runtime:

405 Method Not Allowed

The method GET is not allowed for this resource.

Following is the code: 
is the get mothos creating problem or is there any other solution to get parameter values.

```
class PostBody(webapp2.RequestHandler):
        def post(self):
            stringContent=cgi.escape(self.request.get('txtLocation'))
            stringurl='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query='|stringContent|'&sensor=false&key=mykey'

            result=json.load(urllib.urlopen(stringurl))

            self.response.write(result)
```

Thanks...

Comment: Your URL looks malformed.  You have an `http://` followed by an `https` and a space before `method` and your querystring.  Is this the correct URL you are trying to get?

Comment: ohhh extremely sorry it is typing mistake but the url in the program is correct , there is only one http:// and the problem still prevails..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing

```
def post(self)
```

by

```
def get(self)
```

Comment: No problem. I remembered having this issue at some point as well :)